# How do I find the path to pg_hba.conf from the shell?

Tags: postgresql

I would like to obtain the path to pg_hba.conf from the shell. The path varies between versions of PostgreSQL. For instance, for 8.4 and 9.1:

```
/etc/postgresql/8.4/main/pg_hba.conf
/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf
```

I have tried the `pg_config` command, but it does not seem to include this information.

This is so that I can use a uniform command for opening `pg_hba.conf` and other PostgreSQL configuration files for editing.

I'm using bash.

Comment: How about locate pg_hba.conf ?

Comment: @Pramod There could tens of them lying around. What's if you want to know which one of them is being used by Postgres.

Comment: @BleedingFingers Depending on your setup, you could probably just filter by access time. `find / -name pg_hba.conf -amin -5` (if the server's been restarted in the last 5 minutes; easy enough to change it to `-atime` if it was last restarted a longer time ago). Or you could filter by access time newer than change time or one of the other find time-based options... (Although filtering by `lsof | grep pg_hba.conf` while a server's running doesn't work).

Answer (score 265, accepted):

`pg_config` is for compliation information, to help extensions and client programs compile and link against PostgreSQL. It knows nothing about the active PostgreSQL instance(s) on the machine, only the binaries.

`pg_hba.conf` can appear in many other places depending on how Pg was installed. The standard location is `pg_hba.conf` within the `data_directory` of the database (which could be in `/home`, `/var/lib/pgsql`, `/var/lib/postgresql/[version]/`, `/opt/postgres/`, etc etc etc) but users and packagers can put it wherever they like. Unfortunately.

The only valid ways find `pg_hba.conf` is to ask a running PostgreSQL instance where it's `pg_hba.conf` is, or ask the sysadmin where it is. You can't even rely on asking where the datadir is and parsing `postgresql.conf` because an init script might passed a param like `-c hba_file=/some/other/path` when starting Pg.

What you want to do is ask PostgreSQL:

```
SHOW hba_file;
```

This command must be run on a superuser session, so for shell scripting you might write something like:

```
psql -t -P format=unaligned -c 'show hba_file';
```

and set the environment variables `PGUSER`, `PGDATABASE`, etc to ensure that the connection is right.

Yes, this is somewhat of a chicken-and-egg problem, in that if the user can't connect (say, after screwing up editing `pg_hba.conf`) you can't find `pg_hba.conf` in order to fix it.

Another option is to look at the `ps` command's output and see if the postmaster data directory argument `-D` is visible there, e.g.

```
ps aux  | grep 'postgres *-D'
```

since `pg_hba.conf` will be inside the data directory (unless you're on Debian/Ubuntu or some derivative and using their packages).

If you're targeting specifically Ubuntu systems with PostgreSQL installed from Debian/Ubuntu packages it gets a little easier. You don't have to deal with hand-compiled-from-source Pg that someone's `initdb`'d a datadir for in their home dir, or an EnterpriseDB Pg install in /opt, etc. You can ask `pg_wrapper`, the Debian/Ubuntu multi-version Pg manager, where PostgreSQL is using [the `pg_lsclusters` command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/man1/pg_lsclusters.1.html) from `pg_wrapper`.

If you can't connect (Pg isn't running, or you need to edit `pg_hba.conf` to connect) you'll have to search the system for `pg_hba.conf` files. On Mac and Linux something like `sudo find / -type f -name pg_hba.conf` will do. Then check the `PG_VERSION` file in the same directory to make sure it's the right PostgreSQL version if you have more than one. (If `pg_hba.conf` is in `/etc`/, ignore this, it's the parent directory name instead). If you have more than one data directory for the same PostgreSQL version you'll have to look at database size, check the command line of the running postgres from `ps` to see if it's data directory `-D` argument matches where you're editing, etc.

Comment: This might not be valid for 9.3, I get: `psql: invalid port number: "format=unaligned"` when I run that psql command.

Comment: @jcollum Nope, just a typo. `-P` not `-p`. Fixed.

Comment: This is the only answer that works if you have more than one version of PostgreSQL installed.

Comment: Is there any hope for Postges to standardize this? That would help with installation headaches a lot...

Comment: @ScottSkiles PostgreSQL doesn't control it, it's up to the packages and distributors, who all have strong (and different) opinions on where it should be.

Comment: Thanks, Craig. Does the official PostgreSQL documentation have a strong opinion? Do you have one? :-)

Comment: @ScottSkiles I would like the official PostgreSQL docs to better cover common deployments - the PGDG rpms and debs, the Windows installer, etc. While those are distributed by "PostgreSQL" they're strongly influenced by OS-specific packaging policies etc, so we don't have a free hand. The docs should cover them, but right now they pretty much assume you installed from source despite few users (especially those who need the docs) doing so. I posted on the pgsql-docs list about it recently.

Comment: @ScottSkiles I'd really love some help revising the documentation to better reflect the installs users actually do.

Comment: @CraigRinger - Cool! These docs? https://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/

Comment: @CraigRinger - Is there a place to update the docs? I'm on GitHub but I am having a bit of difficulty figuring out where the docs are hosted :-)

Comment: @ScottSkiles They're DocBook XML in the PostgreSQL source tree, in the `doc/src/sgml/` directory. You can use the authorative sources on https://git.postgresql.org/ or the github mirror.

Comment: in kubuntu v20.04 i used `sudo updatedb ` and `sudo locate pg_hba.conf`

Comment: Thanks. Works on Postgres 14.

Answer (score 41):

This is how I do it:

```
john@host:~$ ls /etc/postgresql
9.1
john@host:~$ sudo vim /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf
```

Since the path is like this: `/etc/postgresql/[VERSION]/main/pg_hba.conf`

Answer (score 12):

Using command-line, ask your database:

```
$ psql -U postgres
postgres=# SHOW config_file;
```

- Copied from Stackoverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3603162/5677857

Answer (score 7):

I am using the following for config files detection:

```
$(ls /etc/postgresql/*/main/pg_hba.conf)
$(ls /etc/postgresql/*/main/postgresql.conf)
```

Answer (score 5):

To find the path to pg_hba.conf, use the command:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -t -P format=unaligned -c 'show hba_file';
```

Answer (score 3):

Editing the correct `pg_hba.conf` with your default visual editor (vim, emacs, nano, joe, etc.) is as easy as:

```
$VISUAL /etc/postgresql/$(ls /etc/postgresql)/main/pg_hba.conf
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply ask from PostgreSQL.

Print pg_hba.conf file location:

```
su - postgres -c "psql -t -P format=unaligned -c 'show hba_file';"
```

Print postgresql.conf file location:

```
su - postgres -c "psql -t -P format=unaligned -c 'SHOW config_file';"
```

Comment: Thank you, but this matches the solution already provided by @CraigRinger

Answer (score -2):

To know where the file is
simply type:

```
pg_lsclusters
```

Comment: If you want to update the pg_hba.conf file then issue the following command:

$ sudo nano /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf

Comment: -bash: pg_lsclusters: command not found

Comment: Command-not-found is telling me this command is available in the postgresql-common package